# Is it possible to select an anchor tag which contains a h1 which contains the text "Visit Site"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chai, cypress

I am using Cypress.io to test my startup's website and would like to select a specific anchor tag.

However, that anchor tag does not have any unique attribute I can use to identify it, therefore I would like to use a child `h1` tag containing the text "Visit Site" to help with identifying the anchor tag.

```
<a href="/blablabla" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer canonical">
  <h1>Visit Site</h1>
</a>
```

I would not be able to use the `href` attribute to help identify the anchor tag, as the written test would be used across other pages of the same structure but of different content.

My issue is that I do not know if its possible to select an element based on whether it contains an element of a certain text.

Comment: If you want to use Cypress commands (not jQuery), `cy.contains('a > h1', 'Visit Site').parent()`. The `cy.contains(...)` yields the `h1` and `.parent()` shifts focus back to `a` and yields it to the next command chained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's contains selector to find the desired h1 based on text inside it. Once h1 is found, just select its parent which will be your anchor.

```
let targetH1 = $('a h1:contains("Visit Site")');

console.log(targetH1.parent()); // this will give you the anchor element
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi As per your question I'm prepared example please check this link 
[Example Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lahtw1k4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").each(function(index,elem){
 let findHeading=$(elem).find("h1:contains('Visit Site')");
  if(findHeading!=undefined)
  {
   console.log("Index "+index);
   console.log("Find H1 "+$(findHeading).html());
  }
  
})
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/blablabla" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer canonical">
  <h1>Visit Site</h1>
</a>
<a href="/blablabla" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer canonical">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</a>
<a href="/blablabla" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer canonical">
  <h1>Visit Site</h1>
</a>
```

**Note:**  you can see the second `A` tag `h1` contain has `hello` word

Answer (score 1):

For the example... I prevented the default behavior of a link (`preventDefault()`).

So using the [`:contains()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), you can target the link containing a particular text.

It will target ALL of the elements matching... But in practice, if you dont iterate the collection, you will have the first one as a result.

Inn the example here... It throws the parent element of a clicked element. So there is no issue. All depends on what you want to do. ;)

Then... Get the `parent()` of that target to get the `href` attribute of the anchor.

```js
$("a h1:contains('Visit Site')").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log("YEAH! " + $(this).parent().attr("href"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/blablabla" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer canonical">
  <h1>Visit Site</h1>
</a>
<a href="/hummphh" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer canonical">
  <h1>Wrong link</h1>
</a>
<a href="/hooo" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer canonical">
  <h1>Other link</h1>
</a>
```